# Gson throws a IOException

Tags: java, json, gson

I have come across the following exception and have no idea why.

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: Expected JSON document to start with '[' or '{'
```

Comment: Can you post some more details? Like the code which throws this exception....

Answer (score 2):

You get this error since your string is not a JSON one. It must start with `{` if it's an object or with `[` if it's an array as stated [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```